# How to get the parents of a Python class?

Tags: python, oop

How can I get the parent class(es) of a Python class?

Answer (score 356, accepted):

Use the following attribute:

```
cls.__bases__
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__):

> The tuple of base classes of a class object.

Example:

```
>>> str.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

Another example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> class B(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> class C(A, B):
...   pass
... 
>>> C.__bases__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>)
```

Comment: To get bases of an instantiated object do `type(C()).__bases__` as mentioned further below

Answer (score 142):

If you want all the *ancestors* rather than just the immediate ones, use [`cls.__mro__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__mro__#class.__mro__).

For versions of Python earlier than 3.5, use [`inspect.getmro`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=getmro#inspect.getmro):

```
import inspect
print inspect.getmro(cls)
```

Usefully, this gives you all ancestor classes in the "method resolution order" -- i.e. the order in which the ancestors will be checked when resolving a method (or, actually, any other attribute -- methods and other attributes live in the same namespace in Python, after all;-).

Comment: You can also just use `cls.__mro__` (at least in Python 3.5)

Comment: @naught101, plz turn it into a full answer. I almost missed it, and so will, I think lots of other people.

Comment: `cls.mro()` also works

Answer (score 65):

The fastest way to get all parents, and in order, is to just use the `__mro__` built-in.

For instance, `repr(YOUR_CLASS.__mro__)`.

The following:

```py
import getpass
getpass.GetPassWarning.__mro__
```

...outputs, in order:

> `(<class 'getpass.GetPassWarning'>, <type 'exceptions.UserWarning'>, <type 'exceptions.Warning'>, <type 'exceptions.Exception'>, <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>, <type 'object'>)`

There you have it.  The "best" answer may have more votes but this is so much simpler than some convoluted `for` loop, looking into `__bases__` one class at a time, not to mention when a class extends *two* or more parent classes.  Importing and using `inspect` just clouds the scope unnecessarily.

Comment: @John Smith  https://stackoverflow.com/users/139885/john-smith, I hope you see this answer.  If you like it, please let me know with an upvote!

Comment: In fact, `inspect.getmro` just calls `__mro__` on object, as you can see in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ded4737989316653469763230036b04513cb62b3/Lib/inspect.py#L486 . Using  `getmro` produces cleaner and more readable code. Though skipping a function call is indeed faster.

Comment: How can I test if a parent class of an instance is the one I'm expecting?
I've tried `isinstance(pre_switch.__class__.__mro__[1], nengo.base.Process)` but it returns `False`.

Comment: I'm finding this helpful with climbing the hierarchy of my Sqlalchemy joined table inheritance orm models. Super simple and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `__mro__` also contains the class itself, such that `A in A.__mro__ is True`, the same does not hold for `__bases__`, so take that in mind if you want to check whether a class is a strict subclass of another.

Answer (score 20):

New-style classes have an `mro` method you can call which returns a list of parent classes in method resolution order.

Comment: What counts as a new-style class? It seems I can use this with Django models, but anything simply inheriting from `object` doesn't seem to respond to `mro`.

Comment: considering an object `x`, we can get the method resolution order with the call

    `type(x).mro()`

we can consider if `x` has `ClassX` as a base class with:

     `ClassX in type(x).mro()`

Answer (score 20):

Use bases if you just want to get the parents, use `__mro__` (as pointed out by @naught101) for getting the method resolution order (so to know in which order the init's were executed).

Bases (and first getting the class for an existing object):

```
>>> some_object = "some_text"
>>> some_object.__class__.__bases__
(object,)
```

For mro in recent Python versions:

```
>>> some_object = "some_text"
>>> some_object.__class__.__mro__
(str, object)
```

Obviously, when you already have a class definition, you can just call `__mro__` on that directly:

```
>>> class A(): pass
>>> A.__mro__
(__main__.A, object)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure they all get called, use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) at all levels.

Comment: Once you use super you have to use it in all levels anyway, which is why you should document it's use explicitly. Also you might want to know that super doesn't work on every class...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **variable** and want to get its **class** and **parent classes** use **type()** method which will give class for a variable

```
val="happy coding"
print(type(val).__mro__)
```

### Output:

```
(<class 'str'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Answer (score 1):

This funciton will print the all the classes of an object, while in each step the next object will the left most parent.

```
def print_root_left(class_):
    while True:
      print(class_)
      # Check there if are no bases then we have reached the root class
      if not class_.__bases__:
        break
      class_=class_.__bases__[0] # use the left most parent


example = "hello" 
print_root_left(example.__class__)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def class_hierarchy(class_name):
    import re
    ancestor = successor = class_name
    level = 0
    print ("The", successor, "has the next parents:\n")
    while True:
        try: 
            ancestor = re.search(r"'(.*)'", str(successor.__bases__[0]))
            print (level, ancestor.group(1))
            successor = eval(ancestor.group(1))
            level+=1
        except: 
            break
#example        
class_hierarchy(IndexError)
```