# Django: How do I get the model a model inherits from?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get python class parent(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611892/get-python-class-parents)

I have a:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    pass

class Cat(Aminal):
    pass

class StreetCat(Cat):
    pass
```

How can I find out the model a model inherits from?

Comment: there are django specific elements here.

Comment: This is not duplicated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the direct superclass in python through `__base__`

```
>>> StreetCat.__base__ is Cat
>>> True
```

`__bases__` will get you a tuple of all parent classes if you have multiple base classes `class Foo(A, B)`

---

**Update thanks to OP: the following django method does not retrieve abstract base classes, as technically these are internal use methods for storing the foreign keys that tie each inherited model to their parents.** Be warned!

Django also indirectly provides some helpers for inherited models which are shortcuts for the pure python methods of traversing the superclasses.

```
>>> StreetCat._meta.get_parent_list() 
[Out] : Set([Class Animal, Class Cat])
```

`InheritedClass.parents` is an ordered dictionary of all parents, so the following would work to get the upper most parent if you wanted:

```
>>> StreetCat._meta.parents.keys()[-1]
```

You could also use a non django related method, something like

```
>>> StreetCat.__mro__[-3] 
# once you know that BaseModel is an Object, and since all defined models subclass 
# the BaseModel, [-3] is the first class that subclasses models.Model
```

Comment: Weird I actually saw that get_parent_list() with dir() and tested it but would only return the direct child.

Comment: You mean the direct parent? That's odd! It sounds like the whole purpose of this method is to get all ancestors. Docstring: 

"""
Returns a list of all the ancestor of this model as a list. Useful for determining if something is an ancestor, regardless of lineage."""

Comment: Ah, seems abstract models are ignored.

Comment: Ahh, good point, because parents is a sorted dict of the one to one fields tying each inherited model table together.

Comment: Loved the __mro__ hack ! a complete neat list as one expect it to be.