# print all SubClass in a SuperClass and all SuperClass in a SubClass

Tags: python

I want in SuperClass print all subClasses and in a subClasses  print all SuperClasses:

```
class SuperClass():
    def Print(self):
        print('my sub classes are : ')
        #print all childs

class Sub1(SuperClass,...):
    def Print(self):
        print('My parents are :')
        #print all SuperClasses

class Sub2(SuperClass,...):
    def Print(self):
        print('My parents are :')
        #print all SuperClasses
```

SuperClass has Print that print all classes that inherit from , and Sub  has Print method that print all his SuperClasses . how do that ?

Comment: Use `cls.__bases` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611892/get-python-class-parents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python classes have three attributes that help here:

- [`class.__subclasses__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__subclasses__); a method that returns all subclasses of the class.
- [`class.__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__), a tuple of the *direct* parent classes of the current class.
- [`class.__mro__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__), a tuple with *all* classes in the current class hierarchy. Find the current class object in that tuple and everything following is a parent class, directly or indirectly.

Using these that gives:

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def print(self):
        print('my sub classes are:', ', '.join([
            cls.__name__ for cls in type(self).__subclasses__()]))

class Sub1(SuperClass):
    def print(self):
        print('My direct parents are:', ', '.join([
            cls.__name__ for cls in type(self).__bases__]))
        all_parents = type(self).__mro__
        all_parents = all_parents[all_parents.index(Sub1) + 1:]
        print('All my parents are:', ', '.join([
            cls.__name__ for cls in all_parents]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> SuperClass().print()
my sub classes are: Sub1
>>> Sub1().print()
My direct parents are: SuperClass
All my parents are: SuperClass, object
```

Comment: I was browsing code mentor and I saw you in there Martjin.How awesome is that!